# jQuery function works on click() not on ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the 'href' attribute to match that of a sibling element.

```
$(function() {
    $(".container").click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find('.one').attr('href');w
        $(this).find('.two').attr('href', href);
    });
})
```

when the 'click();' event handler is used and I click on `.container`, the href of `.two` updates, however, when just using `ready();` to execute it as soon as the page loads, it doesn't execute.

Comment: can you post the whole alternative code using ready() to show what does not work?

Comment: Replace `.click` with `.each`. That should suffice.

Comment: Is that 'w' just after the semi-colon a typo or a cut and past error?

Comment: Can you show us the fiddler ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the context within `.container` element, just change `click` function to `each`, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".container").each(function() {
        var href = $(this).find('.one').attr('href');
        $(this).find('.two').attr('href', href);
    });
});
```

For more information about jQuery's `each` function, please refer [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

**UPDATE**

Also you can improve the performance a bit by caching the value of `$(this)`, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".container").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            href = $this.find('.one').attr('href');

        $this.find('.two').attr('href', href);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

If you don't care about the context of `.container`, here is the code that will change `href` attributes of all those elements with class `.two`, which come after an element with class `.one`.

Here is the [live example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a25kn/2/).

Comment: And why should he use each? Does he have multiple `.container`'s?

Comment: 1. If there is a class selector then it assumed that there can be more than one element. 2. This code will work for both cases.

Comment: .each is the right way to go. If he wanted it to only effect one element he'd made container an ID. His original code effects all classes called container, even if it was just one instance of the class. Best to keep the same functionality in mind.